# Is it possible to identify the user inside a gRPC service using Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I am investigating using gRPC with cloud endpoints for a new project in which I will need fine-grained authorization.  It's simply not clear to me if I'll have a way to identify an authenticated user after ESP has passed the request onto my gRPC services.

I've been pouring over the documentation available for the cloud endpoints solution trying to find a definitive answer to this question, but [This article](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/authenticating-users-grpc) is the best I could find.  It specifies that "Receiving auth results in your API is currently not supported for gRPC services", but I honestly don't know if that means I will not be able to know which user sent the request, or if it means something else.

If you can provide insight, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

That article is wrong. I have fired a ticket to fix the document.

Authentication result is passed to gRPC service as gRPC metadata "X-Endpoint-API-UserInfo".

Answer (score 0):

Note gRPC metadata is keyed lowercase, so use 'x-endpoint-api-userinfo'.